# protecting files in git repository from overwrite without gitignore

Tags: git

How do I protect my local files in a repository from being overwritten by Git without .gitignore? I need to be able to commit/push to the team but I don't want them to change it on my machine.

(please don't answer suggestions about the greatness of .gitignore as I need a solution without it)

Comment: Config files, as usual? :-)

Comment: yes, config ... so far i am just having them zipped outside the repo and I just overwrite them before build

Comment: Are these files checked in or untracked?

Comment: they are checked in ofcourse ... i need to commit/push them to the team but i want to protect them from the team